# Receiver is able to decrypt the data with private key even if sender encrypt the data with modified public key. How is it possible?

Tags: java

We are doing encryption/decryption in Single Sign On with SAML. We have generated self-signed public-private key pair for this. 
SP owns public-private key pair and shares the public key with the IDP so that IDP could encrypt the SAML Assertion. 
Process is as follows:

1. IDP creates SAML Response XML.
2. IDP encrypts SAML assertion and sends SAML Response to SP.
3. SP receives the SAML response and decrypt SAML assertion with the private key.

This part is successfully done.

**Now problem occurs if IDP modifies the public key even a single character from the public key file(.txt format) and sends encrypted Assertion with modified public key then when SP receives SAML response and tries to decrypt the assertion using private key then it successfully decrypts which i am thinking it should not decrypt the SAML assertion. Because public-private key comes in pair and calculated mathematically. One public key can have its corresponding only one private key. Since the SAML assertion is encrypted with wrong public key in that case decryption should not happen with the private key and some error should throw.**

How decryption can still be done with private key if corresponding public has been modified and data is encrypted with modified public key?

We are using **rsa-1_5** algorithm for encryption. Also we have used OneLogin java API to decrypt the SAML assertion.

Please guide us the right direction if we missed out something.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is not really a programming question and would fit better on https://security.stackexchange.com but you should give a specific example; use a test keypair if necessary, although it's safe to publish a real public key because that's what public means. I have seen Qs there about RSA _private_ keys, which are _usually_ stored in 'CRT' format where some parts are effectively ignored and can be damaged unnoticed, but I haven't seen that for public key.

Answer (score 0):

It is not actual public key which i am using for real world application. The format of public file is .txt. Below is the content of public key file:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----